# Binding Button to Listbox Item WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a GUI containing a listbox that holds rows of missing third party updates that resembles the following

[image]

```
INSTALLBUTTON | POSTPONEBUTTON | Application Name ApplicationVersion Upgrade Message
INSTALLBUTTON | POSTPONEBUTTON | Application Name ApplicationVersion Upgrade Message
```

Each row contains two buttons (Install and Postpone) as well as several properties read in from a list (application name, version, number of used deferrals, message that is displayed in red). The datacontext for the listbox is a list.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to bind the Install and Postpone buttons to the applications/rows. This is my current WPF:

```
<ListBox Name="ThirdPartyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,70,0,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="C:\Users\test\Desktop\Project\ACME-WPF\ACME-WPF\window-new-3.ico" Margin="5" Width="50"/>
                <Button Name="ThirdPartyInstallButton" Content="Install" Click="InstallThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25"></Button>
                <Button Name="ThirdPartyPostoneButton" Content="Postpone" Margin="5,5,0,0" Height="25"></Button>
                 <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Item2.Name}" Margin="12,25,0,0"/>
                 <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Item2.RequiredVersion}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.CustomUIMessage}" Margin="10,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Red"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="You have used " Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item3.UsedDeferrals}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                 <TextBlock Text=" of " Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2.MaxDefferals}" Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
                 <TextBlock Text=" deferrals for this update." Margin="3,25,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Once the Install button is clicked I need to execute a method that will trigger an install, using a number of the properties of the associated application list item.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "Click" use the command structures. To get the associated item's data in the command, use the CommandParameter.

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}" Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.InstallComponentCommand}"
```

This assumes that the Window/UserControl's is called "Root". Then, in your code-behind set up a "DelegateCommand" to do the work. This blog post contains a great tutorial on how to set it up: http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html

The bound component object will show up as the object argument of the delegate.

**Update**

In the View Model:

```
public ICommand InstallComponentCommand {get; private set;}

//constructor
{
    InstallComponentCommand = new DelegateCommand(p => InstallComponent(p));
}

private void InstallComponent(object data)
{
    Component componentToInstall = (Component)data;
    // Do whatever is necessary to install
}
```

As far as disabling the button goes, you could set a property like "InstallInProgress" and bind the "IsEnabled" property of the button to it.

Let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this works? This is what I currently have in my install button code:

`private void InstallThirdPartyUpdatesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button ThirdPartyInstallButton = sender as Button;
            DataContext = RegScan_ThirdParty.comparisonListWithState; 
            ThirdPartyInstallButton.IsEnabled = false;
            ThirdPartyInstallButton.DataContext.

                MainEntry.install3PUpdates();
        }`

Answer (score 0):

In the click handler of the button, call the button .DataContext, that should have your object and its properties.

Comment: How do you mean? I can call ThirdPartyInstallButton.DataContext but it doesn't expose any items or properties. I just see the default methods available (e.e. ThirdPartyInstallButton.DataContext.Equals() or ThirdPartyInstallButton.DataContext.ToString().

Comment: @user3430433 you need to cast it into its appropriate type.  If you don't know, do a GetType().ToString()

Comment: Can you provide an example please?